# recursively count sublists beginning with a number

Tags: common-lisp

I am trying to write code in Lisp counting sublists beginning with number, recursively. I ve trying to use `numberp` but my code, when arrived to an atom, doesn't count the rest of the list.

With my code here,

```
(defun nombres (liste) 
  (cond 
   ((atom liste) 0)((atom (car liste)) 0) 
   ((and (numberp (caar liste)) (+ (nombres (cdr liste)) 1)))
   (t (nombres (cdr liste))) ) )
```

I can get a count of sublists but when arrived to an atom , it doesn't count the rest.

```
[67]> (nombres '((a b d) (5 g) (7 m)))
2
[68]> (nombres '((a b d) (5 g) g (7 m)))
1
```

When I test the sublist with (listp (car list), it gives me nil.

```
[69]> (defun nombres (liste) 
  (cond 
   ((atom liste) 0)((atom (car liste)) 0) 
   ((listp (car liste))(and (numberp (caar liste)) (+ (nombres (cdr liste)) 1)))     (t (nombres (cdr liste))) ) )
NOMBRES
[70]> (nombres '((a b d) (5 g) g (7 m) m))
NIL
```

I want to get something like :

```
(nombres '((a b d) a (5 g) (b) (7 m) j (8 h l g))) 
3
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please consider formatting your question for the clarity of it.

Comment: `(count-if (lambda (list) (and (consp list)
                              (numberp (first list))))
          '((a b d) a (5 g) (b) (7 m) j (8 h l g)))`

Answer (score 2):

You need to think about the cases you need to handle.

1. The end of the list => return the result
2. A sublist that has a number in front => add one to the result
3. Anything else => continue to the next element

These will quite easily translate to a `COND`:

```
(cond ((endp list) ...)            ; 1
      ((and (listp (car list))     ; 2
            (numberp (caar list)))
       ...)
      (t ...)                      ; 3
```

Using an accumulator as an optional parameter, the counting is easy to fill in:

```
(defun count-sublists (list &optional (acc 0))
  (cond ((endp list) acc)
        ((and (listp (car list))
              (numberp (caar list)))
         (count-sublists (cdr list) (1+ acc)))
        (t (count-sublists (cdr list) acc))))

(count-sublists '((a b d) a (5 g) (b) (7 m) j (8 h l g)))
;=> 3
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard Common Lisp function `count-if` is easier to use:

```
CL-USER > (count-if (lambda (item)
                      (and (consp item)
                           (numberp (first item))))
                    '((a b d) a (5 g) (b) (7 m) j (8 h l g)))
3
```